# Python 3.x tkinter autocomplete

Tags: python, combobox, autocomplete, tkinter, widget

I know there have been a lot of threads on this, so don't throw garbage at me just yet.

What I'm wondering is if there's a valid, native autocomplete option for the Combobox widget in Tk. Initially I didn't think there was, because the threads I read all seemed to suggest programming your own Class and methods for this purpose and I didn't see reference to it at python.org.

However, I came across this link that seems to suggest that there is an autocomplete option, at least at one time, so I'm wondering 1) is this valid? 2) if valid, why is it not preferred over custom methods and 3) if valid, what's the proper syntax to enable it?

http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/bwidget/BWman/ComboBox.html#-autocomplete

Thanks for your time and attention. Still learning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you linked to is not a built-in widget, it's from an external library. The built-in combobox has never had autocomplete.